# La conexión localhost en Java funciona perfectamente bien hasta que la cambio por una IP

Tags: java, mysql, localhost, ip, appserv

Al insertar "localhost" o mi "ip" más el puerto de AppServ en mi navegador abre correctamente PhPMyAdmin - MySQL, sin embargo, cuando intento anexar el puerto o trato de colocar la IP en el url para la conexión desde mi programa en Java hacia la base de datos, no funciona.

La única manera en que el programa funcione es usando "localhost" (Sin contar la demás ruta) desde mi computadora, pero necesito colocar una IP ya que la conexión que debo hacer se realiza desde otra computadora... funciona en el navegador, pero en el programa no.

Este es el url que funciona:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/BaseDatos";
```

Cualquier otro url deja de servir:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/BaseDatos";

String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.100.8/BaseDatos";

String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.100.8:8080/BaseDatos";
```

Leí que es por un párametro ( bind-adress ) en los archivos de configuración de MySQL, pero NO aparece ese parámetro en los archivos de configuración que encontré así que no sé qué hacer.

Comment: No puedes colocar puertos si no haz configurado un puerto diferente al 80 (puerto por defecto recomendado), cuando el puerto por defecto es 80 no necesitas especificarlo, y si lo especificas en el navegador te redirige directamente a localhost y te quita el puerto (pruebalo), el primer caso y el tercer caso fallan porque le especificas un puerto que no se esta usando o no esta siendo usado por mysql, el segundo no estoy seguro porque falle, una de las posibilidades es que ten en cuenta que la otra computadora o dispositivo solo puede acceder a esa ip si esta conectado a la misma red.

Comment: Otro caso posible del porque falla es que las direcciones ip pueden ser tanto estaticas como dinamicas, en mi pc normalmente son dinamicas, esto significa que pueden estar cambiando cada cierto tiempo (en mi caso camabian cada 10 minutos en linux), asi que talvez tu direccion ip en ese momento coincidio con que cambio y entonces no te funciono, otro punto importante es si `jdbc:mysql` te da acceso remoto, haz la siguiente prueba, ve al navegador y coloca esa direccion tal cual a ver si te muestra `mysql`, si no te lo muestra entonces no esta configurado el acceso remoto.

Comment: La otra posibilidad es que si tengas acceso remoto, pero por cuestiones de seguridad tendras que hacer configuraciones ahora ya de seguridad para que otros dispositivos tengan acceso tambien.

Comment: No se cual es el puerto por defecto de `jdbc`, en el caso de xampp es el puerto 80, pero si en tu caso no es el puerto `80` sino `8080` entonces seria alrevez, el  primer y tercer caso deberia funcionar, el segundo no, puesto que como el puerto por defecto no es `80` entonces si que hay que especificarlo.